# Pouring water from bottles

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, algorithms

> There are three buckets of size $x_1, x_2$, and $x_3$ liters (positive, but not necessarily integers), and some bottles, possibly of different sizes, containing a total of $x_1+x_2+x_3$ liters of water. We want to pour water from the bottles into the buckets. A bottle is *split* if it is poured into more than one bucket. Is it true that for any $x_1,x_2,x_3$, there are bottle sizes such that we need to split two bottles?

By pouring water into the first bucket until it is full, then second bucket, and third, we will never need to split more than two bottles.

For the case $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(1,3,6)$, @WhatsUp's example with three bottles of capacity $10/3$ shows that we do need to split two bottles (that is, splitting one bottle does not suffice).

Comment: If you allow only integer liters, then there are only finitely many case to check. Otherwise consider $7$ bottles, each containing $\frac{10}7$ liters. Then at least two bottles must be split, as none of the three buckets is an integral multiple of $\frac{10}7$.

Comment: I see, you allow to split one bottle two times. So what about three bottles with $\frac{10}3$ liters each?

Comment: My proof that in that case you have to split at least two: otherwise two bottles go entirely into one bucket. This can only be the $6$ liters bucket. But then $\frac{20}3$ liters go into that bucket, which is not possible.

Comment: @WhatsUp Fair enough. I wonder if your example can be extended to any bucket sizes, but it does not seem easy. I updated the question.

Comment: This seems like it could be framed as a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multiple_knapsack_problem) or a [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), which are NP complete in the general case, but not sure if that helps....

Comment: Also, to generalize @WhatsUp 's example, (assuming $x_1\leq x_2\leq x_3$): If there is an integer k for which $x_3<\frac{k-1}{k}(x_1+x_2+x_3)$ and $x_2<\frac{1}{k}(x_1+x_2+x_3)$, then taking k bottles with capacity $\frac{1}{k}(x_1+x_2+x_3)$ forces two bottles to be split using the same reasoning. We can also eliminate the variable k by setting it to the minimum value such that x3 satisfies the condition. That yields that we can force two bottles to be split if (but not only if) $x_2 \left \lceil \frac{x_3}{x_1+x_2} \right \rceil <x_1+x_3$.

Comment: @Dexter hey, you're really welcome for the answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This proof uses the same basic idea of having $N$ bottles with $\frac1N$ of the volume as @mathworker21’s proof and merely provides a more elementary proof of the existence of suitable fractional parts that doesn’t require ergodic theory or linear independence over $\mathbb Q$.

Without loss of generality, rescale the bucket sizes so that $x_1+x_2+x_3=1$. Consider $N$ bottles with volume $\frac1N$ each. The fractional parts of $Nx_i$ can add up to $0$, $1$ or $2$. If we can choose $N$ such that they add up to $2$, it will be necessary to split $2$ bottles (since one bottle can only fill fractional parts that add up to $1$). They add up to $2$ if and only if two of them add up to more than $1$. So we want to show that e.g. $(\{Nx_1\},\{Nx_2\})$ lies in the upper right half of $[0,1]^2$ for some $N$. It would be slightly surprising if it required advanced concepts to show that we can hit an entire half of the square.

If all $x_i$ are rational with common denominator $d$, choose $N=d-1$. Since $\{dx_i\}=0$, we have $\{Nx_i\}=\{dx_i-x_i\}=\{-x_i\}=1-x_i$, and thus $\sum_i\{Nx_i\}=3-\sum_ix_i=2$.

Else, at least two of the $x_i$ must be irrational; assume without loss of generality that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are and that $x_1\lt x_2$. If $x_2\lt\frac12$, some multiple $kx_2$ lies in $\left[\frac12,1\right]$, and either $\sum_i\{k x_i\}=2$ and we are done, or $\sum_i\{k x_i\}=1$ and we can replace the $x_i$ by $\{k x_i\}$; so we can assume $x_2\gt\frac12$.

Since $x_1+x_2\lt1$, by [Dirichlet’s approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) (which can be proved by an elementary application of the pigeonhole principle), there is $M\in\mathbb N$ such that $\{M x_1\}\gt x_1+x_2$ and thus $\{(M-1)x_1\}\gt x_2$. At least one of $\{Mx_2\}$ and $\{(M-1)x_2\}$ is at least $1-x_2$. (This is where $x_2\gt\frac12$ is needed.) Thus, for at least one of $N=M$ and $N=M-1$ we have $\{Nx_1\}+\{Nx_2\}\gt x_2+1-x_2=1$.

Comment: who said it required ergodic theory? I said probably a more elementary proof exists.

Comment: @mathworker21: Yes, I read that and was encouraged to look for one by that remark. I didn't mean to imply that you said no elementary proof exists. All I'm saying is that the concrete proof you gave required ergodic theory (at least that's what I took your remark "all I know is an ergodic theory one" to mean), and I used the same basic idea and made it work without ergodic theory. I didn't mean to diminish your proof; it had the right basic idea.

Comment: no, my bad, you wrote it correctly and I misread. The first sentence is still a bit off to me. It seems you're just giving an elementary proof of Lemma $1$. Anyways, I'm trying to read your solution now. "So we want to show that ({1},{2}) lies in the upper right half of [0,1]2 for some ." It seems this has two issues. First, in the next paragraph, you don't distinguish between $x_1$ and $x_2$. Second, I just have no idea where this came from. You can have two numbers add up to more than $1$ but one of them be less than $1/2$.

Comment: @mathworker21: You seem to be talking about the upper right quarter. By the upper right half I mean the half $x_1+x_2\gt1$, the triangle above the diagonal $x_1+x_2=1$.

Comment: ok, what about first issue? also, why can you replace $x_i$ by $\{kx_i\}$?

Comment: @mathworker21: I don't understand the first issue. Where should I be distinguishing between $x_1$ and $x_2$ and am not? About the replacement: Because $\{N\{kx_i\}\}=\{Nkx_i\}=\{(Nk)x_i\}=\{N'x_i\}$.

Comment: "So we want to show $(\{Nx_1\}+\{Nx_2\}) > 1$" is essentially what you said. And then in the next paragraph, all you show is $\sum_i \{Nx_i\} = 2$. About the replacement: ok

Comment: ok $+1$, nice. I still think you wrote the first sentence ambiguously, to possibly suggest your proof to the puzzle as a whole is different, but maybe I'm just being conspiratorial. In any event, thanks for finding a more elementary proof of Lemma $1$!

Comment: @mathworker21: I intentionally started out by saying that the basic idea is the same as yours so as to acknowledge your work. I can imagine that it sounded to you the way it did because you make a stronger separation into "the proof" and "the lemma", with the lemma just being a side issue and not the main proof. For me, coming up with the $\frac1N$ idea was the easier part (I had that idea independently), and proving the existence of suitable fractional parts seemed more difficult. I've reworded the first sentence and hope that it better expresses my appreciation for your proof now.

Comment: @mathworker21: (By the way, I was the first to upvote your answer.)

Comment: @mathworker21: "all you show is $\sum_i \{Nx_i\} = 2$": I wrote in the second paragraph "They add up to $2$ if and only if two of them add up to more than $1$", so it's enough to show either.

Comment: oh okay, I guess we don't have the same values when it comes to puzzles. To me, figuring out the puzzle assuming whatever math facts you need is the main part, and then proving the math facts is the side business (it took me most of the time to figure out the puzzle). As to your last comment, I don't know how more clear I can make my point. I get that they add up to $2$ iff two of them add up to more than $1$, but why do those two have to be $x_1$ and $x_2$? Maybe reread my previous comments.

Comment: I removed my upvote until my comment is addressed. See my comment starting with " "So we want .." is essentially what you said."

Comment: @mathworker21: I reread your previous comments and unfortunately I still doubt that I understand your question. I'll focus on the last version above: "..., but why do those two have to be $x_1$ and $x_2$"? They don't have to be $x_1$ and $x_2$; any two that add up to $1$ will do. (I'm sorry if I'm stating the obvious instead of answering your question; I'm trying my best to figure out which aspect isn't sufficiently clear.) If not all are rational, at least two are irrational, and without loss of generality I call these two $x_1$ and $x_2$ and assume $x_1\lt x_2$.

Comment: @mathworker21: If that doesn't answer your question (which unfortunately seems likely), please elaborate what you mean by "why do those two have to be $x_1$ and $x_2$?".

Comment: what? i very explicitly referred you to my previous comment: " "So we want to show ({1}+{2})>1" is essentially what you said. And then in the next paragraph, all you show is ∑{}=2". I really don't know how I can be more clear about this, and I'm a bit confused why you didn't reference this comment. To reiterate, I understand that "they don't have to be $x_1$ and $x_2$" as you just said, which is why I'm confused why you initially said "So we want to show ({1}+{2})>1"

Comment: @mathworker21: There's no need to for this tone. I'm doing my best to understand your question, and I apologized in advance in case I wasn't addressing it properly. I'm not blaming you for our failure to communicate on this, and I'd prefer if you didn't blame me, either.

Comment: @mathworker21: I think I see what you mean now. In the second paragraph I'm already referring to $x_1$ and $x_2$ specifically before I write that we can focus on them without loss of generality. I'll fix that. But do we agree that this is just sloppy exposition and doesn't affect the substance of the proof? I think I had a hard time understanding partly because I was under the impression that you were suggesting there might be a gap in the proof.

Comment: @mathworker21: I inserted "e.g." in front of $(\{Nx_1\},\{Nx_2\})$. Does that resolve the issue?

Comment: yes, that resolves the mathematical issue. i didn't mean to bring a rude tone. i just was confused why you were referring to a different comment when i said what comment to look at. also my dad was just yelling at me, so i wasnt completely focused

Comment: @mathworker21: Thanks for explaining, no worries. I'm glad things are resolved now.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Take $N$ as in Lemma $1$ with $\alpha = \frac{x_1}{x_1+x_2+x_3}$ and $\beta = \frac{x_2}{x_1+x_2+x_3}$. Let $b_1,\dots,b_N = \frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{N}$. Suppose we could only split one bottle, giving $\delta_1,\delta_2$ of it to the buckets with $x_1,x_2$ liters (initially), respectively and possibly some to bucket $x_3$. Then there are $m_1,m_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m_1\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{N} = x_1-\delta_1$ and $m_2\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{N} = x_2-\delta_2$. Then $\frac{Nx_1}{x_1+x_2+x_3} = m_1+\frac{N\delta_1}{x_1+x_2+x_3}$ and $\frac{Nx_2}{x_1+x_2+x_3} = m_2+\frac{N\delta_2}{x_1+x_2+x_3}$. Since $\delta_1,\delta_2 < \frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{N}$ (if one of them were equal to $\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{N}$, then one of $\{\frac{Nx_1}{x_1+x_2+x_3}\},\{\frac{Nx_2}{x_1+x_2+x_3}\}$ would be $0$, contradicting that their sum is more than $1$), we see $\frac{N\delta_1}{x_1+x_2+x_3}+\frac{N\delta_2}{x_1+x_2+x_3} = \{\frac{Nx_1}{x_1+x_2+x_3}\}+\{\frac{Nx_2}{x_1+x_2+x_3}\} > 1$, meaning $\delta_1+\delta_2 > \frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{N}$, a contradiction to having split a bottle properly.

.

> Lemma 1: Given any $\alpha,\beta > 0$ with $\alpha+\beta < 1$, there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\{\alpha N\}+\{\beta N\} > 1$.
>
> Proof: If $\alpha,\beta$ are $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent, then $\{(\{\alpha N\},\{\beta N\}) : N \ge 1\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{T}^2$, so clearly a desired $N$ exists. Otherwise, $\beta = \frac{c}{d}\alpha+\frac{p}{q}$ for some $c,d,p,q \in \mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0}$. Then $\{\alpha N\}+\{\beta N\} = \{\alpha N\}+\{\alpha\frac{c}{d} N+\frac{Np}{q}\}$. First suppose $\alpha$ is irrational. Then since $\{\{\alpha N'dq\} : N' \ge 1\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{T}$, we get a desired $N$ by taking $N = N'dq$ with $\{\alpha N'dq\} > 1-\frac{1}{c^2d^2}$, since then $\alpha cqN' = \frac{(k+1)c}{d}-\frac{c}{d}\epsilon$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0 < \epsilon < \frac{1}{c^2d^2}$, meaning $\{\alpha cqN'\}$ is either at least $1-\frac{c}{d}\epsilon$ or at least $\frac{1}{d}-\frac{c}{d}\epsilon$, both large enough. Now suppose $\alpha = \frac{m}{n}$ is rational, with $\gcd(m,n) = 1$. Then write $\frac{m}{n}\frac{c}{d}+\frac{p}{q} = \frac{m'}{n'}$ with $\gcd(m',n') = 1$. We wish to show $\{\frac{m}{n}N\}+\{\frac{m'}{n'}N\} > 1$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$. WLOG suppose $n \ge n'$. We can take $N$ so that $Nm \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$ and $n' \nmid N$; indeed, if $n' \mid n$, then clearly $Nm \equiv -1 \pmod{n'}$ as well, and otherwise, $N = kn+m^*$ for an appropriate $k$ works, where $m^*m \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$. For this $N$, we have $\{\frac{m}{n}N\}+\{\frac{m'}{n'}N\} \ge \frac{n-1}{n}+\frac{1}{n'} \ge 1$, with equality only if $n' = n$ and $mN \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$ and $m'N \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$. But if we had equality, then $(m+m')N \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$, meaning $\alpha+\beta = \frac{m}{n}+\frac{m'}{n} = 1$, which is false.

.

> Fact: If $\alpha,\beta$ are $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent, then $\{(\{\alpha N\},\{\beta N\}) : N \ge 1\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{T}^2$.
>
> Proof: Define $T: \mathbb{T}^2 \to \mathbb{T}^2$ by $T(x,y) = (x+\alpha,y+\beta)$. It suffices to show that $T$ is ergodic w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure. Suppose $f \in L^2(\mathbb{T}^2)$ is $T$-invariant. By basic fourier analysis, $f(x_1,x_2) = \sum_{k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}} c_{k_1,k_2}e^{2\pi i (k_1x_1+k_2x_2)}$. Then $\sum_{k_1,k_2} c_{k_1,k_2} e^{2\pi i (k_1x_1+k_2x_2)} = f(x_1,x_2) = f\circ T(x_1,x_2)= \sum_{k_1,k_2} c_{k_1,k_2} e^{2\pi i (k_1(x_1+\alpha)+k_2(x_2+\beta))} = \sum_{k_1,k_2} e^{2\pi i(k_1\alpha+k_2\beta)}c_{k_1,k_2}e^{2\pi i (k_1x_1+k_2x_2)}$ Therefore, $c_{k_1,k_2} = c_{k_1,k_2}e^{2\pi i (k_1\alpha+k_2\beta)}$ for each $k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $\alpha,\beta$ are $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent, we have $c_{k_1,k_2} = 0$ for all $(k_1,k_2) \not = (0,0)$. It follows that $f$ is a.e. constant, as desired.

Comment: when you say "Otherwise, $\beta = \alpha+\frac{p}{q}$ for some $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0}$", this looks wrong to me. Counterexample : $\alpha=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{9},\beta=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{10}$. Then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are $\mathbb Q$-linearly dependent, but $\beta-\alpha\not\in {\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy sorry, had to do something. should be fixed now.

Comment: If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are linearly dependent over $q$ then $\beta = \frac{c}{d}\alpha$ for some $c,d \in \mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0}$, so you don’t need $p$ and $q$.

Comment: @Dexter there's probably an elementary proof, but all i know is an ergodic theory one. do you know ergodic theory?

Comment: @Dexter added ${}{}$

Comment: I corrected guessed misprints in your answer. Please check.

Comment: @Dexter If $\alpha=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{9}$ and $\beta=\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{10}$, then the three numbers $1,\alpha,\beta$ are linearly $\mathbb Q$-dependent, but the two numbers $\alpha,\beta$ are linearly $\mathbb Q$-independent.

Comment: @mathworker21: I used your idea with $N$ bottles of volume $\frac1N$, and I think I found a more elementary proof that the fractional parts can be made to add up to $2$ (see my answer).

Comment: @joriki I still have to read your answer, but no way the fractional parts can add up to $2$. they are each less than $1$

Comment: @mathworker21: I meant all three fractional parts add up to $2$ (which is equivalent to two of them adding up to more than $1$).